# Error while installing bower package

Tags: node.js, github, bower

while trying to do bower install on node.js command promt im getting the following error

```
bower check-new     Checking for new versions of the project dependencies..
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.com:XXXXX/XXXX", exit

Additional error details:
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Can some one please help me ?

**Note: i'm on a corporate network.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i know it kind of late but this did the trick for me.

Open .bowerrc file and set the proxy configuration.

```
"proxy":"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080",
"https-proxy":"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
```

and then do a run bower install command

Hope it helps !

Comment: I have a similar problem, and I still can't solve it.
when you set the proxy settings, do you replace the "x" with something or put it like that?

Comment: the x here stands for the ip address .. for example your proxy ip address is 192.168.1.2 you need to set the npm config as 
"proxy":"http://192.168.1.2:8080",
"https-proxy":"http://192.168.1.2:8080"

Comment: Thanks!
Actually I solved the problem differently, by removing some lines from the .gitconfig file.

Comment: yeah sure! check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709480/bower-install-error-ecmderr

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be caused because of your corporate network, they might have blocked some ports. 
Try using `https` instead of `ssh`

This is how to change:
`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`