# bower install error ECMDERR

Tags: bower, angular-material, bower-install

I'm trying to follow along angular-material tutoriel http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/ionic/bootstrapping using ionic.

When I tried to do `bower install`, I got the following error:

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git#1.2.4
bower resolve       git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git#1.2.4
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads 
git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git", exit code of #128 ssh: Could not resolve 
hostname https: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Additional error details:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I found many questions here with the same problem, and I lot of them were solved by running

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

But I tried it, and it didn't solve mine.
is there anyway to fix it? if not, is there anyway other than bower to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the .gitconfig file (located for me case in c:/users/my-account-name/ )

I just deleted these lines

```
[url "https:/"]
insteadOf = git://
[url "http://"]
insteadOf = git://
```

and it worked. I think in my case, I shouldn't have run the command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```